# Creating object with means of multiple columns in R to ultimately run t.test

Tags: r

EDIT: I believe I figured out a solution to my question, but I would still appreciate if someone could explain to me why the approach directly below works whereas the approach I tried before (outlined further below in the original question) does not work.

```
average_a<-apply(df[19:38], 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
average_c<-apply(df[39:58], 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

I am trying to create two variables that contain the average values for certain columns so that I can ultimately run a t.test.

```
A1U_sweet  A2F_dip  A3U_bbq  C1U_sweet  C2F_dip  C3U_bbq
1          2        1        NA         NA       NA
NA         NA       NA       4          1        2
2          4        7        NA         NA       NA
```

In the past, I have used the following approach. I have then been able to run a t.test comparing average_A and average_C.

```
average_A<-data.frame((mean(A1U_sweet, na.rm = TRUE)), (mean(A2F_dip, na.rm = TRUE)), (mean(A3U_sweet, na.rm = TRUE)))
average_C<-data.frame((mean(C1U_sweet, na.rm = TRUE)), (mean(C2F_dip, na.rm = TRUE)), (mean(C3U_sweet, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I recently tried the following approach. This is more efficient because I have many columns and prevents me from having to type them manually. EDIT: Why doesn't this work?

```
dfa<-df[19:38]
average_A<-lapply(split.default(dfa, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfa))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
dfc<-df[39:58]
average_C<-lapply(split.default(dfc, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfc))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I thought that this would give me the same result as the previous, longer way of doing this. However, when I try to run a t.test to compare average_A and average_C, I get the following error:

```
Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What is the difference between my first and second approaches to this problem? How can I modify the second approach so that I can use the subsequent objects to run analyses like t.tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might lie in the way you subset the dataframe.

I turned your data into a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(A1U_sweet = c(1, NA, 2),
                 A2F_dip = c(2, NA, 4),
                 A3U_bbq = c(1, NA, 7),
                 C1U_sweet = c(NA, 4, NA),
                 C2F_dip = c(NA, 1, NA),
                 C3U_bbq = c(NA, 2, NA))
```

Then your solution worked. However, you do need to unlist the result of the `lapply()` before running the t.test.

```
dfa <- df[,1:3]
average_A<-lapply(split.default(dfa, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfa))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
dfc <- df[,4:6]
average_C<-lapply(split.default(dfc, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfc))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
t.test(unlist(average_A), unlist(average_C), paired = F)
```

If you use `sapply()` instead of `lapply()`, you don't need to unlist anything because `sapply()` returns vectors instead of lists

```
dfa <- df[,1:3]
average_A<-sapply(split.default(dfa, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfa))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
dfc <- df[,4:6]
average_C<-sapply(split.default(dfc, sub("\\d+.*", "", names(dfc))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
t.test(average_A, average_C, paired = F)
```

Also, I know you didn't ask, but another solution would be

```
t.test(sapply(grep("A.*", names(df)), function (i) mean(df[,i], na.rm=T)), 
       sapply(grep("C.*", names(df)), function (i) mean(df[,i], na.rm=T)),
       paired = F)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say I need to "unlist" the result of lapply(), and why is this important?

Comment: If you type `str(average_A)` (on the version that is the result of the `lapply()`) you will see that the object is a list. If you do the same thing on the version of `average_A` that is the result of an `sapply()` you will see that it is a numerical vector.  The `t.test()` function only accepts vectors, not lists, as its `x=` and `y=` arguments. `unlist()` unlists lists so allows you to convert list objects into (in this case) vectors.